# Fetching a Git Branch Under a Different Name

Tags: git, version-control, fetch

I want to know if I can fetch a Git branch from a remote repo, but store it under a different name in my local repo. It happens to be the `master` branch of the remote repo, but I'd like it to show up as, say, `featureX`.

I know it's possible to `push <remote> local_name:remote_name` (on the initial push) to change the name that will show up in remote. Basically I want to do that in reverse, without the other repo having to rename its `master` branch. Any configuration options required to make the future fetches/pulls behave correctly with the `featureX` name would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
git fetch <remote>
git checkout -b <local-branch> <remote>/<remote-branch>
```

Alternatively if you already have `<local-branch>` and just want it to track `<remote-branch>`:

```
git checkout <local-branch>
git branch -u <remote>/<remote-branch>
```